# Calling soap web service without stub

Tags: java, soap, base64, jax-ws, jaxb2

I am trying to call a web service without auto generated classes. Normally, It is easy to do that. But, one of web service parameters is base64 data. Using wsimport or wsdl2java are not options for me.
So how can I call the web service with base64 param?
Thank you.

Comment: How about an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It is very hard to share sample because of privacy. I can say that wsdl and xsd are seperate. When I try to generate with wsdl2java, I get two input point error.

Comment: if you can't share anything SO might be the wrong place for your question...

Comment: Thank you. I am just looking for theory. Are there any solution for calling a webservice with base64 param without stub classes.